# Monte Carlo Integration by sampling according to general measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Is the following statement true:

Let $f: C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function, where $C \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ compact. Let $\mu$ be a probability measure over $C$. Furthermore, let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $X_n \sim \mu$. Then

$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(X_n) = \mathbb{E}_{\mu}[f]= \int_C f d \mu$ almost surely.

Proof:
Define $Y_n := f(X_n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. As $f$ is bounded, $Y_n$ is a bounded random variable. By [Popoviciu's inequality on variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popoviciu%27s_inequality_on_variances#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20Popoviciu%27s%20inequality,with%20a%20particular%20probability%20distribution.), $Var(Y_n) = \sigma^2 < \infty$. Therefore, the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) applies and the statement follows.

I am hesitant because there are hardly any restrictions on $\mu$. The compactness of $C$ rules out things like a Cauchy distribution.

I am thankful for any pointers and sources on this.

Comment: Strong law of large numbers, not central limit theorem!

Comment: Yes, thank you! I changed the question accordingly!

Comment: SLLN for iids actually only demands absolute integrability. It's much harder to prove in this case but it holds anyway.

Comment: Just to actually answer your question: Yes, this is true, even without compactness of $C$.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up a few more things for me. So, apparently, SLLN (by Kolmogorov's second version) holds for any bounded i.i.d. random variables. This is independent of the measure $\mu$, as far as I understand.

Comment: Yes, the underlying set does not really matter. In probability theory we usually abstract it out completely, except for rare occasions when foundational matters arise (raising questions about whether a probability space with certain properties even exists). (For example, once you know that a sequence of iid $U(0,1)$ variables exists, you can already do any problem about sequences of iid random variables.)